# I am having trouble to send mail,so are there anyone how may help me?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble to send mail from my contact form page. Here is my code, may anyone help me to fix this ?

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div id="form_wrap">
            <form>
                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" />
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
                <label for="email">Your Message : </label>
                <textarea  name="message"  value="Your Message" id="message" ></textarea>                       
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary" placeholder="support@arterydigital.com">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this. The simple concept one:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $to = 'support@arterydigital.com';
   $subject = 'New Info';
   $headers = "From: ".$name."."-".".$email."\r\n";
   $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

   //send it now ...
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
   echo "Successfully sent";
?>
```